# How to assess the goodness of a text generation algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, philosophy, generative-adversarial-networks

Take a RNN network fed with Shakespeare and generating Shakespeare-like text.

Once a model seems mathematically fine, as can be assessed by observing its loss and accuracy over training epochs, how can one assess and refine the goodness of the result ?

Only human eyes can judge of the readable character of a text, its creativity, its grammatical correctness etc.

QUESTION : Which systematic approach can be used to refine a generative model (text) ?

Comment: How would you measure the quality of the output text?

Comment: That's a philosophical question, at first, it should be readable and correct, which is already a challenge when tuning generative models

Comment: So you could, as a very basic metric, use readability scores (though they have loads of faults).